# openapi-generator doesn't generate response headers for Java client using Spring Webclient

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, openapi-generator

We have an openapi file (validated) that declares response headers, e.g.

```
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "OK",
        "schema": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "results": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/CourseV2"
              }
            },
            "paging": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/PagingInfo"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "results"
          ]
        },
        "headers": {
              "X-RateLimit-Limit": {
                "type": "integer",
                "description": "Request limit per hour."
              },
              "X-RateLimit-Remaining": {
                "type": "integer",
                "description": "The number of requests left for the time window."
              },
              "X-RateLimit-Reset": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time",
                "description": "The UTC date/time at which the current rate limit window resets."
              }              
          }           
      },
```

Using java webclient client generated by [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) project (maven or cli,), the return type of the invocations are not including response headers, nor the invokeAPI methods in ApiClient class does give access to the response headers.
Indeed the ApiClient invoke methods are returning a Mono/Flux of the return type, thus no permitting to get response headers

```
public <T> Mono<T> invokeAPI(String path, HttpMethod method, Map<String, Object> pathParams, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, Object body, HttpHeaders headerParams, MultiValueMap<String, String> cookieParams, MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams, List<MediaType> accept, MediaType contentType, String[] authNames, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> returnType) throws RestClientException {
    final WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBuilder = prepareRequest(path, method, pathParams, queryParams, body, headerParams, cookieParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames);
    return requestBuilder.retrieve().bodyToMono(returnType);
}
```

As far as I know, the only way to have access to response headers using Spring Webclient is using toEntity that gives a ResponseEntity methods (and thus .getHeaders) instead the bodyToMono.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you get to a solution?  am seeing similar issues.

Comment: @Upen take a look at my comment below

Answer (score 1):

Indeed spring-based templates for openapi-generator do not mention response headers. However these headers are supported by the generator core engine, and templates for some generators contain /some/ support for them. Particularly, one can look at the template for `scala-akka-client`: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/scala-akka-client/api.mustache#L38

Additionally Swagger Annotations used for example for Java-Spring template allow to specify ResponseHeaders for a given Response.

So far so good. One can try to enhance templates for a chosen generator. In case of Java/Spring generator it would be https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/api.mustache

However, it seems that the current openapi-generator data model is somewhat incorrect.

First of all, responseHeaders are bound to a method, not to a particular response of the method. It means one can't have different headers for different responses (e.g. one for `200` and another for `412`) that seems to be a serious deficiency.

Secondly, in order to make the generator produce types necessary for headers (particularly, enums), these headers should **not** use built-in schemas, all schemas are to be placed into `#/components/schemas/` and then referenced from a corresponding header:

```
components:
  headers:
    Repeatability-Result:
      description: |
        a header to implement server-side machinery for idempotency of requests
        complying to OASIS Repeatable Requests Version 1.0
        https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/repeatable-requests/v1.0/repeatable-requests-v1.0.html
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/RepeatabilityResult'
      required: true
  ...
  schemas:
    RepeatabilityResult:
      description: |
        a header to implement server-side machinery for idempotency of requests
        complying to OASIS Repeatable Requests Version 1.0
        https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/repeatable-requests/v1.0/repeatable-requests-v1.0.html
      type: string
      enum:
        - accepted
        - rejected
```

Next,the generated types are not included into {{{imports}}} so one to deal with this manually.

Additionally, the header type description seems irrevocably lost in the generator type definition.

And finally, right now I don't understand how a proper
Java/WebFlux-specific API method definition should look like.

I can include `responseHeaders` into `@ApiResponse` definition like this:

```
@ApiResponse(value = 204,
    responseHeaders = {
        @ResponseHeader(name = "ETag", response = String.class),
        @ResponseHeader(name = "Repeatability-Result", response = org.example.RepeatabilityResult.class)
    },
    message = ....
)
<webflux-specific API method declaration>
```

But it seems it's only for informational purposes, and does not bring any new functionality. One still has to put necessary headers to the response manually, without any support/validation from the framework.

I can file a bug to OpenAPI-Generator, but at first I would like to understand how a proper solution could look like.