# Add response headers using openapi-generator

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am trying to add "Content-Disposition" header to my api response. This api downloads a file. Here is how I configured the json specification file for openapi-generator (for java spring):

```
"/download": {
      "get": {
        "description": "Returns the file",
        "operationId": "getFile",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description":"A file",
            "headers": {
              "content-disposition": {
                "description": "Content disposition header",
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "example": "attachment; filename=keyFile.pem"
                }
              }
            },
            "content": {
              "application/octet-stream": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "binary"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Delete operation not allowed"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "File not found"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But the code generated by openapi-generator does not add the header to the response. The swagger UI also does not show any header in the response.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426763/openapi-generator-doesnt-generate-response-headers-for-java-client-using-spring) says that adding headers is not supported in spring generator for openapi-generator. Is this true? If yes then, is there an alternative to this?

Can somebody help me with this? I am pretty new to spring-boot and open-api.