# Open Api generator doesn't add any information about response headers to generated code

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi-generator, response-headers

I have following open api specification description:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
...
  /foo:
    get:
      operationId: foo
      parameters:
        - name: bar
          in: query
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: description
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
          headers:
            myheader1:
              description: myheader1 desc
              schema:
                type: string
            myheader2:
              description: myheader2 desc
              schema:
                type: integer
        401:
          description: "Unauthorized"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
```

The generated code is:

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-01-24T14:16:01.056664+03:00[Europe/London]")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "Default", description = "the Default API")
@RequestMapping("${openapi.directoryServiceManager.base-path:/api/v1}")
public interface DefaultApi {

    /**
     * GET /foo
     *
     * @param bar  (required)
     * @return description (status code 200)
     *         or Unauthorized (status code 401)
     */
    @Operation(
        operationId = "foo",
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "description", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class)))
            }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDto.class))
            })
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/foo",
        produces = { "application/json" }
    )
    ResponseEntity<List<String>> foo(
        @NotNull 
@Parameter(name = "bar", description = "", required = true, in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "bar", required = true) String bar
    );

}
```

As you can see there is no information about response headers(`myheader1` and `myheader2`)

I would expect that

[ApiResponse](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.1.1/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/responses/ApiResponse.html#headers--) should have **headers** argument added

Is there way to fix it ?

More information about environment:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:5.0.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.21"  
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.4"
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "6.3.0"
}
```

### UPDATE

Based on advise in comment I tried to update versions:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:7.2.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.21"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.4"
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "6.5.0"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "11.5.0"
    jacoco
}
```

Generated code still doesn't contain any information about response headers:

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-01-24T16:42:30.088851100+03:00[Europe/Moscow]")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "Default", description = "the Default API")
@RequestMapping("${openapi.directoryServiceManager.base-path:/api/v1}")
public interface DefaultApi {

    /**
     * GET /foo
     *
     * @param bar  (required)
     * @return description (status code 200)
     *         or Unauthorized (status code 401)
     */
    @Operation(
        operationId = "foo",
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "description", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class)))
            }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDto.class))
            })
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/foo",
        produces = { "application/json" }
    )
    
    ResponseEntity<List<String>> foo(
        @NotNull 
@Parameter(name = "bar", description = "", required = true, in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "bar", required = true) String bar
    );

}
```

Comment: Person, who flagged the question. What clarity do you need ? I provided MRE, provided expected and actual result. What should I add in addition ?

Comment: OpenAPI generator version 6.3.0 is an old version (current version is 7.2). Did you try with a newer version of the OpenAPI generator?

Comment: I see only 6.5.0. Will try it
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapi.generator/org.openapi.generator.gradle.plugin

Comment: @Thomas Kläger please read topic update

Comment: For the latest gradle plugin, please refer to https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.openapi.generator instead.

Comment: @WilliamCheng I use it and mentioned it in the question. Should I remove smth ?

Comment: please open  an issue in the github repo with the details for tracking.

Comment: @William Cheng Is it ok ?
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/17695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like the problem you are facing doesn't have any simple solution this far. As it comes from the answer to this question: [openapi-generator doesn't generate response headers for Java client using Spring Webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426763/openapi-generator-doesnt-generate-response-headers-for-java-client-using-spring)

> spring-based templates for openapi-generator do not mention response
> headers

Here's the template for `JavaSpring`: [JavaSpring/api.mustache](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/api.mustache)

And this one is for `scala-akka-client`: [scala-akka-client/api.mustache](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/scala-akka-client/api.mustache#L38)

As you see, unlike the second one, the first doesn't declare any reference to `{{#responseHeaders}}`:

```
responses = {
            {{#responses}}
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = {{#isDefault}}"default"{{/isDefault}}{{^isDefault}}"{{{code}}}"{{/isDefault}}, description = "{{{message}}}"{{#baseType}}, content = {
                {{#produces}}
                @Content(mediaType = "{{{mediaType}}}", {{#isArray}}array = @ArraySchema({{/isArray}}schema = @Schema(implementation = {{{baseType}}}.class){{#isArray}}){{/isArray}}){{^-last}},{{/-last}}
                {{/produces}}
            }{{/baseType}}){{^-last}},{{/-last}}
            {{/responses}}
```

Moreover, there is an issue filed, describing similar problem: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11061 and it's not fixed AFAIK.

In theory you could try to use your custom template for code generation, but as it comes from the response mentioned above, you'll have the same headers for all responses and this contradicts your schema (custom headers are applied only to `200`).

Comment: So we have to wait for feature implementaion ?

Comment: Yes, I guess we have to wait. Alternatively one could fork the repo and implement it